# Integral using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> How can we compute the integral of 
>   $ \int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz$ , where $f(z) = z \sin(z) / (z+2) + \bar{z} $

I think we need to use  Cauchy's integral formula, but I am not sure how?

Comment: For $\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{z \sin(z)}{z+2}dz$ you should use the Cauchy integral **theorem**, and for $\int_{|z| = 1} \overline{z}dz$ use the definition  $\int_\gamma g(z)dz = \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ denote the unit circle parametrised in the anti-clockwise direction. Split:
$$ \int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_\gamma \frac{z \sin z}{z + 2} dz + \int_\gamma \overline{z} dz
$$
The former is holomorphic within $\gamma$, so...

The second integral should be easy to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D:=\{z \in \mathbb C:|z|<3/2\}$. Then $g(z):=z*sin(z)/(z+2)$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Thus (Cauchy !): $\int_{|z|=1}g(z)dz=0$

A direct calculation gives  $\int_{|z|=1} \overline{z}dz=2 \pi i$